# How to get Node ID's with cypher request that's using properties(n)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get all properties and the ID's of SomeNode's and OtherNodes's.

I have this query:

```
const neo = driver.session();
const responseObj = { error: false, message: 'success: getting nodes' };

const q = 'MATCH (n:SomeNode)-[:has]->(o:OtherNode), ' +
' RETURN properties(n) AS node, properties(o) AS otherNode';

neo.run(q)
 .then((result) => {
  const records = result.records;
  const nodes = [];

  records.forEach((record) => {
    nodes.push({
      node:  record.get('node'),
      other: record.get('otherNode')
    });
  });

  responseObj.nodes = nodes;
  neo.close();
  respond(null, responseObj);
});
```

This gives me back an array of objects with SomeNode's properties and OtherNode's properties, as expected, but I also need the id's of SomeNode and OtherNode. What is the best way to accomplish this?

How to get ID if node is returned?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map projection](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/maps/#cypher-map-projection) to get the properties of a node and customize, such as by adding an additional map property.

```
MATCH (n:SomeNode)-[:has]->(o:OtherNode)
RETURN n {.*, _id:id(n)} AS node, o {.*, _id:id(o)} AS otherNode
```

Though returning `n` and `o` directly should include the id by default.

Comment: What is correct way to get id if I just return node?

Comment: I don't see node.properties.id...?

Comment: Depends on how you're consuming the output. If you look at the Code view tab of the results in the browser, you should see the id in the returned data. If accessing the results via a neo4j driver, you should be able to similarly access the identifier of a returned node result (on the same level as `properties`, not within them).

Comment: I'm only seeing identity, labels, properties (on same level as properties).

Comment: `identity` is the internal neo4j id.

Comment: inside identity there is high, low - they are both zero

Comment: That has to do with the way javascript represents numbers. Neo4j uses 64-bit integers (aka long values), but javascript can't represent these with its numeric data types. Here's the relevant portion in the driver readme: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#a-note-on-numbers-and-the-integer-type

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158310/discussion-between-cmac-and-inversefalcon).

Answer (score 1):

You could use map projection to return the id along with the properties, for example :

```
MATCH (n:Company) RETURN {properties: properties(n), id:id(n)}
```

-

```
{"properties":{"desc":"Programmable 4thgeneration array",
 "name":"Homenick-Feeney"},"id":"2111"}
```

But then, why not just returning the node itself, the only info you would have more is its labels ?

Comment: I like using properties(n) cause it just gives back properties and I don't have to do node.properties.prop, if I do just return the node what is correct way to get id?

Comment: can you dump the debug of the object, it should be there

Comment: @InverseFalcon got it. Had to convert to javascript number `node.identity.toNumber()`